# Convert jQuery Object to String upon AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Let's say I submit a form with anything in the value of `user_input` like "I am free." I submit it through AJAX and it gets returned to me as a string. Ok now it's an Object... how would I turn that into a string?

Thank you,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <title>Sin título 3</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="result_target" style="display:none;"></div>
<form id="form_to_post" action="#" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="example.php" />
<input type="text" name="user_input" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit"  />
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#form_to_post").submit(function() {

var hiddenURL = $("input[name=url]");
var userInputForm = $("input[name=user_input]");

//var dataString = "userInput="+inputForm;



$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: hiddenURL;
data: {userInput: userInputForm},
success: function(return_contents) {
//returns jquery object...
var output =//
$("#result_target").html(output);
}
});

});

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the object (JSON result) look like?  You should be able to just specify output=return_contents.field_returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get values from inputs

```
data: {userInput: userInputForm.val()},
```

Comment: Sometimes I really do have a brain-lapse. I knew this. I just forgot. Thank you.

Comment: @weka no worries.  It happens to me all the time too :)